# UVW mapping for triangle mesh with 2d jpeg texture

Tags: graphics, 3d, mapping, textures, mesh

I recently downloaded a 3d triangle mesh (.obj format) off of Turbosquid that came with a 2D jpeg image as a texture. I plan on using this mesh in a program I am developing where I am writing my own code from scratch to parse the .obj file and then texture and render the mesh.

My program can currently handle doing this just fine in most cases but there are a couple of things off with this particular .obj file that I don't know how to handle.

1) The UV coordinates are not in the range [0,1]. 0 is still the minimum value but there seems to be no upper bound. I assume this is meant to indicate that the texture wraps around the mesh more than once, so I've decided to extract the decimal value for each coordinate and use that. So for each coordinate I'm currently doing the following:

```
double u = ReadInValue();
double v = ReadInValue();
u = u - (int)u;  
v = v - (int)v;
```

So a UV coord that's [1.35, 3.29] becomes [0.35, 0.29]. The texture still looks a bit off when applied so I'm not sure if this is the right thing to be doing.

2) There is an extra W coordinate. I realize that if I was dealing with a 3D volumetric texture file, the W coordinate would function in the same way as the UV coordinates and would simply be used to look up the value in the 3rd dimension. However the texture file I am given is *two dimensional.* So what do I do with this extra W coordinate? Can I simply ignore it? Do I have to divide the UV coordinates by the W term (as if its a homogenous coordinate?) I'm not quite sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can't extract just a fractional part of texture coordinates and expect it to work. This will break for triangles that goes over [1,1] or below [0,0]. For example a line with vertices UVs [0,0] and [5,5] - this should mean that texture will be wrapped 5 times, but in your computations both vertices get [0,0]. GPU don't have problems with using UVs bigger than 1.0 or even negative so just use what you have.

2) We don't know what is exactly in your model, it could be done for 3D texture so it has 3D coords but since you said it came with 2D texture then I don't think it's the case. I'd suggest to use first answer, with just `u,v` coords and see what you get.

Comment: For 1) how would I just "use what I have"? How would I use a UV [5,5] as is without converting it to the range [0,1]? If i have a texture thats 4000 x 4000 pixels, then what does [5,5] correspond to? When you have UVs in the range [0,1] you can think of the coordinates as being percentages, so uv [0.5, 0.5] would be pixels x = 2000, y = 2000. This is why I thought it best to extract the fractional part.

Comment: Imagine a texture space not as `[0,0]->[1,1]` but as an infinite space with your texture tiled side-by-side, and your triangles lie on this space. For example, when you render a sand beach you don't need big sand texture - you may use small `4x4/8x8` texture, but set your coords to be big (like [0,0]->[100,100]), so the texture repeats many times. The same may apply to your model, depending on the texture contents.